# Preventing blurred/compressed images with Twitter integration and Photobucket

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, twitter

Photobucket seems to be the default repository for images that are tweeted using iOS 5's built-in twitter integration. But Photobucket compresses these images a lit, blurring them, in some cases making them not usable (depending on the application). Is there any way to prevent this? Either some way to tell PB not to compress, or tell the Twitter framework to use a different photo sharing service, any method to make these images ok.

I can instead have the same exact image attached to an email and it looks fine, no blurriness, so it is getting introduced in the twitter process.